# How to return highest salary of employees in each department and their employee number and department number?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm studying SQL and I've found a problem I can't understand.

The challenge is to use two different tables to return the highest salary of employees in each department and their employee number and department number?

This is table 1. It tells me to which department each employee number belongs
[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbrgl.png)

Then in table 2, I can know each employee's salary by employment number.
[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcHZA.png)

I've tried this

```
WITH a AS (
SELECT dept_no, dept_emp.emp_no, salary AS 'maxSalary'
FROM dept_emp
JOIN salaries
    ON dept_emp.emp_no = salaries.emp_no
ORDER BY salary DESC   
)
SELECT *
FROM a
GROUP BY dept_no
ORDER BY dept_no;
```

The answer I get is very close except (i get 4 out of 5 right and one wrong)
[Comparison between my query and the right query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzPDj.png)

The right answer is this one:

```
select de1.dept_no,de1.emp_no,s1.salary as maxSalary
from dept_emp as de1 inner join salaries as s1
on de1.emp_no = s1.emp_no
and de1.to_date = '9999-01-01' and s1.to_date = '9999-01-01'
where s1.salary in
(
select Max(s2.salary)
from dept_emp as de2 inner join salaries as s2
on de2.emp_no = s2.emp_no
and de2.to_date = '9999-01-01' and s2.to_date = '9999-01-01'
and de2.dept_no = de1.dept_no
)
order by de1.dept_no
```

Even after I look at the right answer don't really understand why my code is failing.

If you could let me know what I'm missing here would really appreciate.

Comment: Two biggiest:  `order by` in subqueries and CTEs is meaningless.  `GROUP BY` with `SELECT *` should be a syntax error.  Your approach is not correct.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your question should be somthing like that

```
select dept_emp.emp_no, dept_no, max(salary)
from dept_emp
inner join salaries on dept_emp.emp_no = salaries.emp_no
group by dept_no;
```

Answer (score 0):

The secret sauce you're missing that's found in the correct query is this:

```
where s1.salary in (derived table)
```

What's happening here is that when you attempt to pull max(salary) AND employee numbers at the same time, you're going to get all employees with a single salary value per department.  This problem must be broken into two pieces:

table 1:

- group by department number
- max(salary)

table 2:

- all salaries
- all departments
- all employees

When you join t1 and t2, you're doing so on t1.salary = t2.salary AND t1.DeptID = t2.DeptID.  In t2 when you get that employee, you're basically looking them up as a function of the salary they earned.  e.g. if Bill makes $15/hour and Ted makes $14/hour while both are in the Excellent department, then Bill is the one you're going to find in t1 by virtue of the max(salary) in the Excellent department for t1 = $15/hour.

A point of confusion you might have is that the correct query says "salary in (derived table)", but that's just another way of doing an inner join on salary = salary".  There's more than one way to get the right answer!

If it were me, i'd do it like this (I avoid CTEs unless absolutely necessary):

```
SELECT
    t2.EmpID
    ,t1.DeptID
    ,t1.MaxSalary
from
    (select -- get max salary per department
        DeptID
        ,max(Salary) as MaxSalary       
    from
        emp
        join sal on emp.EmpID = sal.EmpID
    group BY 
        DeptID
    ) t1
    join
        (select 
            emp.DeptID
            ,sal.Salary
            ,emp.EmpID
        from
            emp
            join sal on emp.EmpID = sal.EmpID
        ) t2 on t1.DeptID = t2.DeptID and t1.MaxSalary = t2.Salary
;
```

In this result, only Bill gets pulled from the join because only Bill makes $15/hour for the joins in t1 and t2 for that department.